# Delete first 10 Lines From Multiple Files

Tags: find

The files are named `file00` through `file99` (hundred files). They are all in the same directory. How do I grab all the hundred files and delete the first 10 lines from each file? I am using CentOS 7.

Answer (score 4):

This will delete the first ten lines from all files whose names range from `file00` to `file99`:

```
sed -i.bak -n '11,$p' file[0-9][0-9]
```

This might require GNU `sed`, which is known as `gsed` on OSX.  For other seds, try:

```
find file[0-9][0-9] -maxdepth 0 -type f -exec sed -i.bak -n '11,$p' {} \;
```

**How it works:**

1. `-i.bak` tells sed to modify the files in-place, creating a backup file with the .bak extension
2. `-n` tells sed not to print any lines unless we explicitly ask it to.
3. `11,$p` tells sed to print lines starting with line number 11 and continuing to the last line (denoted `$`) in the file.
4. `file[0-9][0-9]` is a shell glob that will expand to match all files whose names consist of `file` followed by two digits.

#### Alternative

The logic can be inverted.  Instead of explicitly printing the lines 11 and after, we could (hat tip: JigglyNaga) delete the first ten lines:

```
sed -i.bak '1,10d' file[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Incrediblly fast :) and probably the best solution..

Comment: Works if `sed` resets the line numbers inbetween files. (not on OS X)

Comment: You could avoid needing the `-n` flag with `1,10d`.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Yes, that works.  Answer updated to add the `1,10d` approach.

Comment: But, this might have a disadvantage if say file `file34` is a link. The op has not specified any requirements about this

Comment: Your `find` is required to be GNU `find`, or another `find` that understands `-maxdepth`.  Most (on the free Unices) actually do, and the OP is on Linux, so it's prolly ok.

Comment: @Kusalananda `-maxdepth` is supported not just by GNU find but also by  [OSX find](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) and [freeBSD find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)).  Which versions of `find` are you aware of that don't support it?

Comment: As I said, _most_ `find` implementations _do_ support the flag. AIX, Minix, and Tru64 `find` doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Using a simple loop in `bash` (or any Bourne-like shell) and GNU or BSD `sed`:

```
for f in file[0-9][0-9]; do
  sed -i '.bak' '1,10d' "$f"
done
```

The `sed` editing script `1,10d` will delete lines 1 through to 10 from the input stream. The other lines will be outputted. With `-i '.bak'` we ask `sed` to do the editing in-line in the file, but to back up the original with a `.bak` suffix.

Alternatives with explicit looping (allows for sub-intervals, `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh` syntax):

```
for (( i = 0; i < 100; ++i )); do
  f="$( printf "file%02d" "$i" )"
  sed -i '.bak' '1,10d' "$f"
done
```

Using `ksh93` or `zsh`, another way:

```
typeset -Z 2 j
for (( i = 0; i < 100; ++i )); do
  j=$i
  sed -i '.bak' '1,10d' "file$j"
done
```

The `typeset -Z 2 j` will force `$j` into a zero-filled number of width 2. We don't want to `typeset` `i` in this way as its value would turn into `00` once it reached 100, effectively turning the loop into an infinite loop. That's for `ksh93`, `zsh` seems able to handle it as it apparently uses the value before submitting it to the formatting.

Comment: Good catch about ksh93 and i=100 _becoming_ as opposed to _expanding to_ 00.  Compare `zsh -c 'typeset -Z2 i; i=100; echo "$i $((i))"'` with the same with `ksh93`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It's verges on being a bug in ksh93 IMHO.

Comment: Another way to do ranges / steps: `for i in {0..9}{2,4,6,8,0} 100;do ...`, or `seq`  For a one-off by hand, it's generally not a problem to generate a filename that you know won't exist (like `00`).

Answer (score 3):

To avoid creating temporary files or affecting the permissions, ownership or other attributes of the files, with `ksh93`:

```
for f in file{2}([0-9]); do
  tail -n +11 < "$f" 1<>; "$f"
done
```

The `<>;` redirection operator acts like `<>` (open in read+write mode), except that the shell truncates the file upon the command exiting successfully at the position the command left it.

So, we're basically overwriting the file over itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a bash loop:

```
for f in file[0-9][0-9]; do
    tail -n +11 "$f" > tmp &&
    mv -f tmp "$f"
done
```